# Is it good to process Entities from DB in Java Stream with Hibernate and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, java-stream

For example, I want to fetch collection of entities from database using Spring Data JPA, modify them and update in database:

```
repository.findAll().stream.map(e -> ...).forEach(e -> repository.save(e));
```

or I want to create new entities and save them into DB using Stream API, etc...

What are the best practises?
Can Stream API with database connection cause problems?

Comment: `repository.saveAll(Iterable<T>)` is more efficient when saving bunch of entities

Comment: yes, it is just an example. I am asking in general about manipulation with entities from DB in Stream API

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should avoid this kind of manipulation with database because is an anti-pattern: to get all data with `findAll()` and after it to start processing, when you can do it with database `SQL UPDATE Statement` for example or can find another approach

For more details why it is an anti-pattern,
please read about it [**spring-data-findall-anti-pattern**](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-findall-anti-pattern/)

Comment: yes, `.findAll()` method is written just for example. it can be
`repository.findAllByName(name)`

Comment: I understood it and also how i said in my opinion is a bad practice because you can do it directly in database with an `UPDATE query` without fetching it and do some manipulation with `Stream API`.